# How to configure angular with a provider that needs async initialization?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a serviceProvider that needs some async init. I want my controllers to access this service only if the init is finished.

```
angular.module("myModule").provider("AsyncInit", {
    myThing: {},
    init: function(options) {
        doSomeAsyncStuff(options).success(function(newThing) {
            myThing = newThing;
        });
    },
    $get: function() {
        return {
            theThing: myThing
        }
    }
});

//Initialisation of myModule 
angular.module(myModule)
    .config(function(AsyncInitProvider) {
        AsyncInitProvider.init(options);
    })
```

if I access `AsyncInit.theThing` in a controller it is not initialized at first but is later. This seems logical to me.

Is it possible to wait until the service is fully initialized?

Comment: Is this related to the resolve option on ngRoute? http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx

Comment: I don't have routes but I'll take a look at how it is implemented there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to start the async call in the configuration process of your provider than you could use $interval.

```
this.$get = function($q, $interval) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var handler = $interval(function() {
    if (myThingHasBeenLoaded) {
      $interval.cancel(handler);
      deferred.resolve(myThingsValue);
    }
  }, 100);

  return {
    getMyThing: function() {
      return deferred.promise();
    }
  };
}

// In your controller:
myThingService.getMyThing().then(function(myThing) { console.log(myThing); } );
```

I use this to load the Google experiments API and it works great. The interval will check all 100ms if your thing has been loaded successfully and then resolves the promise. The obvious catch here is that it only resolve every 100ms regardless of if your thing loads in 1ms. **I would strongly suggest just to use a simple promise instead IF you don't have to make the async call in the configuration step:**

```
angular.module("myModule").provider("AsyncInit", function () {

  this.options = {};

  this.init = function(options) {
    this.options = options;
  };

  this.$get = function($q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var self = this;
    return {
      getMyThing: function() {
        doSomeAsyncStuff(self.options)
          .success(function(newThing) {
            deferred.resolve(newThing);
          })
          .failure(function(errors) {
            deferred.reject(errors);
          });

        return deferred.promise();  
      }
    };
  };
});
```

The code in your controller would be the same as in the example above.